# Problem about Props emit on vuetify table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 page that contain app and /component/datatable.vue but when I click method EditedItem it have problem.

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "editedItem"

How should I do this?

This is my page:

```
<template >
  <v-container>
    <v-col>
      <Datatables
        :headers="this.headers"
        :items="items"
        :editedItem="editedItem"
        :defaultItem="defaultItem"
        sort-by="calories"
        class="elevation-1"
      />
    </v-col>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <br />
    <v-col></v-col>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Datatables from "../../components/Datatable/CrudDatatable";
export default {
  components: {
    Datatables
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
          align: "start",
          sortable: false,
          value: "name"
        },
        { text: "Calories", value: "calories" },
        { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat" },
        { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs" },
        { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein" },
        { text: "Actions", value: "action", sortable: false }
      ],
      items: [],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {
        name: "",
        calories: 0,
        fat: 0,
        carbs: 0,
        protein: 0
      },
      defaultItem: {
        name: "",
        calories: 0,
        fat: 0,
        carbs: 0,
        protein: 0
      }
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.initialize();
  },
  methods: {
    initialize() {
      this.items = [
        {
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0
        },
        {
          name: "Ice cream sandwich",
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3
        }
      ];
    }
  }
};
</script>


<style>
</style>
```

this is my component

```
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" sort-by="calories" class="elevation-1">
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat color="white">
        <v-toolbar-title>My CRUD</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">New Item</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>

                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Dessert name"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.calories" label="Calories"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.fat" label="Fat (g)"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.carbs" label="Carbs (g)"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.protein" label="Protein (g)"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
      <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    headers: {
      type: Array
    },
    items: {
      type: Array
    },
    editedItem: {
      type: Object
    },
    defaultItem: {
      type: Object
    },
    editedIndex:{
      type: Number
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
  }),
  computed: {
    formTitle() {
      return this.editedIndex === -1 ? "New Item" : "Edit Item";
    }
  },
  watch: {
    dialog(val) {
      val || this.close();
    }
  },

  methods: {

    editItem(item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item);
      this.editedItem = Object.assign(this.items[this.editedIndex], this.item);
      this.dialog = true;
    },
    deleteItem(item) {
      const index = this.items.indexOf(item);
      confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?") &&
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
    },
    close() {
      this.dialog = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
        this.editedIndex = -1;
      }, 300);
    },
    save() {
      if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
        Object.assign(this.items[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem);
      } else {
        this.items.push(this.editedItem);
      }
      this.close();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't update the prop because it will just get recalculated.

So everywhere where you update the prop, for example, you could change from:

```
this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
```

to:

```
this.$emit("updateEditedItem", Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem));
```

Then on Datatables you have something like:

```
<Datatables @updateEditedItem="editedItem = $event"
```

This will update the prop by passing editedItem through the parent again.

[Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), [Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)